# factor graphs - example

Tags: graph-theory

I am self-studying graphs - and stumbled upon factor graphs - e.g. as described on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_graph. I have trouble concretizing what the factor vertices represent. Would anyone be able to give an example based on a simple function that one factorizes? many thanks